# How do I get cron to email me only when AIDE detects file modification?

Tags: linux, bash, cron, aide

I set up a crontab. I've installed AIDE and I have an AIDE database to check for file integrity.

How do I get cron to email me **ONLY** when files have been modified?

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash 

if aide -c /etc/aide/aide.conf --check
    then echo "AIDE detected no changes"
else
    echo "Alert!: AIDE detected changes!"
```

The crontab:

```
* */12 * * * /root/script.sh | mail root@localhost.com
```

Comment: Replace `echo "AIDE detected no changes"` with `:`?

Comment: Or, `if ! aide -c /etc/aide/aide.conf --check; then echo "Alert!: AIDE detected changes!" fi`? or `aide -c /etc/aide/aide.conf --check || echo "Alert!: AIDE detected changes!"`?

Comment: I think you need to do more than that.  On my system `mail foo@bar < /dev/null` sends an email with an empty body!!

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: Mayken / @Dharman - My apologies.

Comment: Any more of this and we will need to mod-flag this Question to have it locked by the diamond moderators.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `MAILTO` crontab variable rather then piping to `mail`.  Then change your script so that it doesn't output anything unless there is a problem:

```
#!/bin/bash 
aide -c /etc/aide/aide.conf --check || echo "Alert!: AIDE detected changes!"
```

The crontab:

```
MAILTO=root@localhost.com
* */12 * * * /root/script.sh 
MAILTO=""
```

Notes:

1. You can use a simple (local) username instead; e.g. `root`.
2. You need to have set up mail handling on your system; e.g. delivery to local mailboxes or relaying via an external SMTP serice provider such as Gmail.  That is beyond the scope of this Q&A.
3. The `MAILTO=""` is to stop following cron rules from sending mails.  If you *want* them to do that, leave it out.  It must be `MAILTO=""` not `MAILTO=`.  (Cron is not implementing shell syntax here.  Another clue is that the you can put spaces around the `=` which you can't do with shell syntax.)
4. Setting of variables in `crontab` is not part of the [POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/crontab.html).  There have been many implementations of `cron` over the years and not all of them support variable setting.  Check what `man 5 crontab` says on your system.

---

Alternatively, you could use `... | mailx -E root@localhost.com` rather than `... | mail root@localhost.com`.  This will skip sending the mail if the body (i.e. stdin) is empty.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get cron to email me ONLY when files have been modified?

If you are on Linux with a local [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) (e.g. [ext4(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext4.5.html) or [BTRFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs)), consider using [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) facilities and then install `incrond` (on Debian or Ubuntu: the `incron` package) and use [incrontab(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/incrontab).

Be aware that `incron` and `inotify` don't work on remote file systems such as [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) or [SMB/CIFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) or on pseudofile systems like [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

If you cannot use `incron` you'll need to use [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) and perhaps [stat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) in your shell script periodically called by `cron`

BTW, some files (e.g. those under `/var/run/`, see [hier(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html) for more) are very often modified. And so are the data files handled by [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDBMS) such as [PostGreSQL](https://postgresql.org/)

Regarding [AIDE](https://aide.github.io/), be sure to read its documentation. Since it is [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) and even [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html), consider studying then improving its code (e.g. to use `inotify`).

Answer (score 1):

We wrote a Perl script that sends out an email if something went wrong *and* updates the database so that this email won't go out again.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $aide =  "/usr/sbin/aide -c /etc/aide.conf";
my $email = "security\@your-domain.com";
my $timestamp = `/bin/date +\%Y-\%m-\%d.\%H-\%M`;
my $output = "";
my $added = -1;
my $removed = -1;
my $changed = -1;
my $warning = 0;
my $found_no_differences = 0;
open(AIDE, "$aide --check|");
while (my $line=<AIDE>) {
    chomp($line);
    $output = $output.$line."\n";
    if ($line =~ /Added entries\:\s*(\w+)/) { $added = $1; }
    if ($line =~ /Removed entries\:\s*(\w+)/) { $removed = $1; }
    if ($line =~ /Changed entries\:\s*(\w+)/) { $changed = $1; }
    if ($line =~ /WARNING\:/) { $warning = $warning + 1; }
    if ($line =~ /AIDE found NO differences/) { $found_no_differences = 1; }
}
close(AIDE);
if ($found_no_differences > 0) { exit(0); }
if ($added > 0 || $removed > 0 || $changed > 0 || $warning > 0 || $added == -1 || $changed == -1) {
    open MAIL, "|mail -s 'AIDE $timestamp' $email";
    print MAIL $output;
    close MAIL;
    system("$aide --init");
    system("mv /var/lib/aide/aide.db.new.gz /var/lib/aide/aide.db.gz");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

by default aide sends email to local root user, it's probably best to create an alias for the local root user to noc@domain.com or whatever you use for your incoming email address, this way you not only get aide emails but also other system mail that's destined for the user root